# Reliable Reverse SSH Tunnel

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm using `autossh` to open a reverse SSH tunnel using private keys. The tunnel user's shell is `rssh` and is verified as working.

The problem I'm having is as such, regardless of ClientAliveInterval (`15`) and ClientAliveCountMax (`3`) (the `sshd` defaults), on the client side the tunnel is opened with:

```
exec autossh -N                   \
  -o "ServerAliveInterval 60"     \
  -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3"      \
  -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no"   \
  -R ${tunnel_port}:localhost:22  \
  -i ./tunnel                     \
  -v                              \
  tunnel@directory.mytunnelhost.com
```

The `${tunnel_port}` comes from a small `curl` call which looks for a free port on the tunnel host, the port doesn't change (it's assigned based on the mac address of the requesting box)

The problem is that when `TERM`inating the tunnel client, the ports stay occupied on the host, and the sshd process keeps running:

[image]

I also can't log into the machines via the tunnel:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-252-138-233:~$ ssh -p 39777 pi@localhost
ssh: connect to host localhost port 39777: Connection refused
```

I'm wondering what I can do to make the tunnel more reliable, to make sure when either end goes down that it's completely dead, torn down and can't enter a "broken" state.

If I was tunnelling over port 80 or similar, I could write a `check` script (this daemon os started with `runit`) to check that some HTML page was available end-to-end through he tunnel, however when it's over SSH, and as a reverse tunnel, I'm at a loss as to how the client could know if the tunnel is really *working* as against just running?

Comment: If possible, you may want to consider a dedicated VPN service instead, such as OpenVPN.  Using a VPN service instead of a SSH tunnel will typically gain you some additional benefits, such as automatic handling of tunnel disconnects.  I don't know your environment so I can't say this is a solution or answer, and besides, a VPN would be off-topic for the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have two questions here.

First is how to make sure that the server sshd processes terminate, freeing up the ports, once the client disconnects.  If the client disconnects then I don't know why the server processes would hang around, unless maybe they have child processes, but your screenshot shows that they don't.  If the client doesn't disconnect but just stops responding, then the server process should terminate by about ClientAliveInterval*ClientAliveCountMax seconds later.

Second is how the client can determine whether the tunnel is working.  This is what autossh's port monitoring feature does.  If you add e.g. `-M 20000` to the call to autossh, it will set up port forwards to send traffic to the remote host on port 20000, and receive it back on port 20001.  It will try to send traffic around the loop every AUTOSSH_POLL seconds (default 600), and if it detects that the connection has stopped working, terminate it and start a new ssh connection.

Adding the `-M` switch to your autossh call, and probably setting AUTOSSH_POLL lower, to say 30, may help if ssh hasn't been terminating correctly.

Comment: With ClientAliveInterval 5, ClientAliveCountMax 1 - the tunnel ports on the host are dropped immediately, as expected. As for the AUTOSSH_POLL, I haven't needed to play around with that yet.

Comment: Accepting because the answer related to the ClientAlive* variables for SSHD.